# How to reuse or factorize code?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am currently writing a lot of Firebase Functions and some of them share the same variables and functions. 
At the moment I copy paste them in each Firebase Functions file, as they are siloed, but I don't know what would be the best practice to share the code between them? For the variables a config file would be cool, for the code, a class all Functions could inherit too, but I'm not sure how to do it clean?

Organization: at the moment I have an index.js file that is referencing all Firebase Functions that I have. Each Firebase Functions is a JS file. That's the hierarchy I have, not optimal nor maintainable...

Examples

- Variables:
  I currently have to write the API key of Mailgun in all my Firebase
- Function: 
  getThisProcessDone() that I currently copy in all my Firebase Functions

Anyone already had the thought? Thanks for your help!

Comment: There have been a few questions about how to modularize Cloud Functions for Firebase, i.e. putting each function in its own node module. Is that what you're looking for?

Answer (score 3):

For my Functions projects, I've been putting my reusable resources into `functions/lib` and requiring them normally as npm modules. I've also been separating out the code used in Functions from the definitions, which helps with testing.

For example, consider this structure:

```
functions/
 |-index.js
 |-newWidget.function.js
 |-lib/
 |  |-Widget.js
test/
 |-newWidget.functions.spec.js
```

Now if I want to declare a trigger to handle new widgets, I do something like the following:

```
// functions/index.js:
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
exports.processNewWidget = functions.https.onRequest(require('./newWidget.function.js').process);

// functions/newWidget.function.js
exports.process = function(req, res) {
   res.send('Hello world!');
};

// test/newWidget.function.spec.js
// Note how we can easily test our widget processor separate from
// the third-party dependencies!
const newWidget = require('../functions/newWidget.function.js');

describe('newWidget', () => {
  describe('process', () => {
     it('should send hello world', function() {
        const req = {};
        cost res = { send: () => {} };
        spyOn(res.send);
        newWidget.process(req, res);
        expect(res.send).toHaveBeenCalledWith('Hello world!');
     });
  });
});
```

And to include a class called Widget from inside newWidget.functions.js, I do something like this:

```
// functions/lib/Widget.js
class Widget {
   constructor(name) { this.name = name; }
}

exports.Widget = Widget;

// functions/newWidget.function.js
class Widget = require('./lib/Widget').Widget;

exports.process = function(req, res) => {
   const widget = new Widget(req.param.name);
   res.send(widget.name);
};
```

Comment: Thanks Kato, I would go with your suggestion, nevertheless looks like the class syntax doesn't work. For example when I try to do "class Widget = ..." I have an error "Unexpected token =" while building :(

Comment: Sounds like you have an old version of node?

Answer (score 1):

Having your functions under a GitHub repo and calling them from master branch isn't an option? I am currently importing like this in package.json:

```
{
    "name": "functions",
    "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
    "dependencies": {
        "cex-converter": "https://github.com/joaquinperaza/cex-converter/tarball/master"
        },
    "private": true
}
```

then you just require your conde dependency like `require('cex-converter')` and you get the last release of your dependency and doesn't need to modify anything to deploy your last release.

Comment: Thanks Joaquin, I'm gonna first try Kato solution then if it is stable enough I will definitely package everything and do as you said :)